# Are there languages without the /j/ sound as in English "yellow"?

Tags: phonology, pronunciation, list-of-languages, phonemes

There are many languages without the /w/ sound as in English *world*, as in French *oiseau*, as in Spanish *fuego*, and as in Mandarin *wang* (the last three respectively mean *bird*, *fire*, and *king*). Some famous examples include: Russian, Yiddish, Albanian, Armenian, Greek, and Turkish.

But, languages without the /j/ sound as in English *yellow*, and French *caillou* (which means pebble) seem to be extremely rare.

So, why is the /j/ sound so common in human languages?

Comment: Spanish, at least some varieties (Venezuelan?). Also Wutung (Sko family, Papua New Guinea).

Comment: Also Ancient Greek (which had /j/ at an early stage but lost it).

Comment: Polynesian languages, like Hawaiian, Māori, Rapanui, Samoan, etc.

Comment: They exist, but it's true they're rare. Cf. [this](https://phoible.org/parameters) database, which lists /j/ as the third most frequent consonant at 90%, significantly above /w/ at 82%.

Comment: Korean doesn't have a consonant w but gets the same sound by combining o and a vowels as if in English you say, "oh all" a w sound comes out when you say that.

Comment: @TKR only as its own phoneme. [j] did exist in diphthongs. In Attic it was present in: υι, ει (when not a spurious diphthong representing /e:/), οι, αι, and the long diphthongs ῃ, ῳ, & ᾳ. If the OP is asking about the phone (as the use of the phrase "the __ sound" suggests) then Ancient Greek would not seem to fit. If they are talking about phonemically (as the use of slashes often suggests, albeit in a slight abuse of notation per the IPA) then it would

Comment: Korean absolutely does have both /w/ and /j/ sounds (phonemes), it just lacks standalone letters for these sounds. (In Korean orthography, they are combined to the following vowels.)

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Spanish dialects was a good thought but I think in cases like *tiene* or anything with *ñ* they still have it, no?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer sure phonetic [j] occurs all over the place in Spanishes, but as the question refers to /j/, ie between slashes, I assumed it was referring to a phoneme. So yes it occurs at hiatus (_tiene_), but _ñ_ is surely a single phoneme (post-alveolar palatal?), not [n] + [j].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples drawn from Phoible are Ket, Khasi, Garo, Malay (Standard), Iai, Kaliai, Maori, Hawaiian, Asmat, Kunimaipa, Nasioi, Kalaallisut, Eastern Ojibwa, Ticuna, Ocaina, Guarani, Liberian Kpelle and Khoekhoe. However, one should also dig into the original data sources. A non-original data source, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ket_language), cites [qàj] 'elk' in Ket; the unglossed root *<layang> = [lajaŋ]* is given in the Wiki page on [Malay phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_phonology). Wiki includes [j] in the inventory for [Kalaallisut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_language#Phonology), but Phoible also lists [j] as an allophone of the phoneme /ʝ/ (dunno why the phoneme is deemed to be /ʝ/ and not /j/). It also lists [j] as an allophone of /ɲ/ in Liberian Kpelle, but also drawing on a different source, it is a full-fledged phoneme. Having worked on the Guinean dialect, I would agree that /j/ is a phoneme of Kpelle, and certain exists as a sound of the language. In other words, some of the gaps are artifacts of analysis. The one case that I am mostly convinced of is Khoekhoe, having worked on the language: it has no [j] at any level, though Hagman in his grammar suggests that [j] exists in loanwords (no examples are given).

A bizarre "example" is Finnish, which according to one Phoible source (Stanford Phonology Archive) has no *j* (!!!?), because the phoneme is actually /e̯/ and [j] is merely an allophone. There's really no doubt that Finnish has /j/ (*jarvi, jalka, joki*).

Comment: How come that Standard Malay has no /j/?.. What about words like _Melayu_ /məlaju/ “Malay”, _saya_ /saja/ “I”, _yang_ /jaŋ/ “which”? Consider the Jawi (Arabic alphabet) spelling of _yang_, a frequent word, which is يڠ <yŋ> – if it began with a vowel like /iaŋ/, it would begin with an alif ا, which is always the case with word-initial vowels.

Comment: Did you mean _järvi_?

Comment: I learned a little Liberian Kpelle.  It definitely has an initial /j/ in words like "ya," meaning "water"; "yɛɛ" meaning "in that way"; and in the semi bound form "yee," meaning "hand."  In normal citation form, these words might have an added low-tone non-syllabic palatal nasal phoneme (nyai, nyɛɛ, and nyee) that might have complicated a linguist's analysis to make them believe [j] could not exist on its own.

Comment: Greenlandic (Kalaallisut) definitely has /j/. I don’t think there’s any real need to distinguish between [j] and [ʝ] – I believe they’re in pretty free variation word-initially, and intervocalically I’ve only ever heard [j]. In initial position, I _think_ it’s only found in loan words like [_juulli_ ‘Christmas’](https://en.wiktionary.com/wiki/juulli) (from Danish _jul_); but intervocalically, it’s not uncommon in native roots as well, such as [_ajor-_ ‘be bad’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ajorpoq).

Comment: How can you be certain that Finnish [j] is not an allophone of /e̯/? Is there a minimal pair?

Answer (score 2):

In Russian, the consonants are arranged into 4-member squads: hard voiceless, hard voiced, soft voiceless, soft voiced. The [й'] sound is voiced counterpart of [х'], and voiced soft counterpart of [х]. Thus, this squad is lacking only voiced hard member. This sound, by the way, can be found in Ukrainian.

So, I think, having voiceless velar fricative [х] in your language or its allophones (such as uvular fricative) strongly prompt you to have its contrasting soft, voiced and soft voiced squadmates.

Comment: [й'] has a completely different place of articulation from [х'] though

Comment: @Lorraine For me, no. The only difference is voicing.

Comment: Really? I am not native Russian speaker, but I believe you are. Do you pronounce отдохни with a soft х? Does it sound like отдойни? Or, can you think of a better example?

Comment: @Lorraine no, in отдохни [х] is hard.

Comment: @Lorraine try "хер. ер." in this synthesizer: voicebot.su